# ORA-00904: : Invalid Identifier in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently working on a SQL assignment, but first I need to create tables which it is not letting me do. I have 3 tables which are Customer, PurchasedDeal, and Usage. I manage to create the first 2 tables successfully, but I am having a little difficulty with creating the Usage table. For some reason it is giving me this error.

```
Error at line 2:
ORA-00904: : Invalid Identifier
```

If anyone could help me understand why it is giving me this error I would really appreciate it. Thanks. It is saying it is having problems with uID INT and I am using putty to create these tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
CustomerID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerName VARCHAR(100),
Phone VARCHAR(15)
);

CREATE TABLE PurchasedDeal(
DID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
dealName VARCHAR(100),
cost FLOAT,
totalValue FLOAT,
balance FLOAT,
CustomerID INT,
FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID)
);

CREATE TABLE Usage(
uID INT,
uDate DATE,
cost FLOAT,
DealID INT,
PRIMARY KEY(DealID, uID),
FOREIGN KEY(DealID) REFERENCES PurchasedDeal(DID)
);
```

Comment: `uID` is reserved word for Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm

Comment: What is the requirement for those `float` columns, by the way? I've never seen `float` used in a production system, and even though I've read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-75209AF6-476D-4C44-A5DC-5FA70D701B78) I have to say I'm not sure why anyone would choose it. Also, it's `varchar2`, not `varchar`.

Answer (score 1):

The term ‘uid’ is reserved in Oracle. This term cannot be used as a column name in the Oracle environment.
Query: SELECT uid FROM t1
Result: will execute correctly

Query: SELECT U.”uid” FROM x.t1 U
Result:  will through error:
ORA-00904: “U”.”uid”: invalid identifier 00904. 00000 – “%s: invalid identifier”

Query: SELECT U.”UID” FROM x.t1 U
Result: will execute correctly as uid is replaced with UID (in capital)

Rectification in below table and we are good to go.
CREATE TABLE Usage(
uID1 INT,
uDate DATE,
cost FLOAT,
DealID INT,
PRIMARY KEY(DealID, uID1),
FOREIGN KEY(DealID) REFERENCES PurchasedDeal_test(DID)
);